# CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:3 (project): No CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER could be found. flutter desktop

Tags: flutter, cmake, flutter-desktop, flutter-windows

Iam trying to build a flutter desktop application .
i followed the configuration here
https://docs.flutter.dev/desktop
i installed visual studio 2022 with and add Desktop development with C++ to it .

but when i tried to run a run a desktop application it said

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:3 (project):
  No CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER could be found.



Exception: Unable to generate build files
```

here is my flutter doctor

```
[√] Flutter (Channel master, 3.1.0-0.0.pre.1111, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19043.1706], locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 3.1.0-0.0.pre.1111 at E:\softwares\flutter\flutter_windows_2.0.5-stable\flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 52c47e96a3 (7 days ago), 2022-06-05 08:03:02 -0400
    • Engine revision 075947bf4d
    • Dart version 2.18.0 (build 2.18.0-170.0.dev)
    • DevTools version 2.14.0

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 31.0.0-rc3)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\zamzam107019\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Platform android-31, build-tools 31.0.0-rc3
    • Java binary at: E:\softwares\flutter\android studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.12+7-b1504.28-7817840)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

[√] Visual Studio - develop for Windows (Visual Studio Community 2022 17.2.3)
    • Visual Studio at E:\vs community
    • Visual Studio Community 2022 version 17.2.32526.322
    • Windows 10 SDK version 10.0.19041.0

[√] Android Studio (version 2021.2)
    • Android Studio at E:\softwares\flutter\android studio
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.12+7-b1504.28-7817840)

[√] Connected device (3 available)
    • Windows (desktop) • windows • windows-x64    • Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19043.1706]
    • Chrome (web)      • chrome  • web-javascript • Google Chrome 102.0.5005.63
    • Edge (web)        • edge    • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge 102.0.1245.39

[√] HTTP Host Availability
    • All required HTTP hosts are available

• No issues found!
```

and this is the cmake line that cause the error

```
# Project-level configuration.
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)   
project(truck_scale LANGUAGES CXX)   <---
```

i tried too many solution but no thing succeeded

Comment: How do you configure the cmake project? What's the default cmake generator? (`cmake --help`  should mark it with an `*`.)

Comment: @fabian                                                                                                               `* Visual Studio 17 2022        = Generates Visual Studio 2022 project files.
                                                Use -A option to specify architecture.
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It solved when i modified Desktop development with C++ and installed Windows 10 SDK **10.0.20348.0** instead of **10.0.19041.0**

[image: Visual Studio installer modification]

Comment: The compiler isn't part of the SDK, so it's almost certainly the case that what fixed it was that you re-ran the installer (fixing wherever went wrong during the initial installation), not the SDK change.